# How JVM check which type of exception occurred in a program?

Tags: java, exception

How does the JVM get information on what type of exception occurs, and then shows what type of exception it is, as well as which thread is used by JVM to inform us.

Comment: Do you mean how it generates the stack trace? Or how exceptions are thrown? Could you give an example of what you mean

Comment: sir in following program JVM show Exception ---------public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="1";
    int a=Integer.parseInt(s); } ------- there how JVM get information that there is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:28)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0):

The programmer can *throw* an *exception* using the [`throw`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) statement. The *bytecode* uses the *opcode* [`athrow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.athrow):

> The objectref must be of type reference and must refer to an object
>   that is an instance of class Throwable or of a subclass of Throwable.
>   It is popped from the operand stack. The objectref is then thrown by
>   searching the current method [(§2.6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) for the first exception handler
>   that matches the class of objectref, as given by the algorithm in
>   [§2.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10).
>
> If an exception handler that matches objectref is found, it contains
>   the location of the code intended to handle this exception. The pc
>   register is reset to that location, the operand stack of the current
>   frame is cleared, objectref is pushed back onto the operand stack, and
>   execution continues.

See [2.10. Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10) from JLS to better understand exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Java Developer defines a function to throw Exception under some criteria as in FileNotFound Exception. Exception to this is Runtime Exceptions which can occur anywhere is the code eg. NPE.

If an Exception is catched it will no longer propagate which means you have to handle it. If you do not catch the Exception then it will just propagate to it's parent calling function. This process will continue till main() method. If even main() does not handle it JVM will simply shut down.

Also there is no separate reporting thread. Same main thread which executes the code takes care of Exception handling.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 types of exceptions : checked and unchecked.

Checked exceptions are exceptions that need to be caught in your program. They are subclasses of "Exception".

Unchecked exceptions are exceptions that don't need to be caught. They are subclasses of "RuntimeException".

JVM can throws RuntimeExceptions like OutOfMemoryException or NullPointerExeception.

But some frameworks or you, can explicitly throw exception (checked or unchecked, depends of your needs).